# Insert List of Parameters Function into DB

Tags: python, postgresql

I use `inspect` module trying to insert a list of parameters of Python function into PostgreSQL DB. I managed to get thses parameters printed but not inserted into DB. I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Code:

```
 import inspect
 def func(a, b, c):
 frame = inspect.currentframe()
 args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
 for i in args:
   cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (a,b,c) " + (i, values[i])) #doesn't work
   print "    %s = %s" % (i, values[i]) #works

 cx.commit()
```

Comment: What is your objective when you want to use `inspect` for inserting values in a database ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle I was trying to save them into list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this statement is the problem:

```
cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (a,b,c) " + (i, values[i])) #doesn't work
```

under for loop, you are executing each **i** in **args**, which translated to:

```
cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (a,b,c) " + ('a', 1))
cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (a,b,c) " + ('b', 2))
cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (a,b,c) " + ('c', 3))
```

however your **VALUES** has 3 values **(a,b,c)** so it throws an error, put your execute statement after for loop should work:

```
args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
for i in args:
    print "    %s = %s" % (i, values[i]) #works

cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (%s,%s,%s);", tuple(values[a] for a in args) ) 
cx.commit()
```

And in fact you can simply just execute without **args** (not sure why you want to extract args from inspect rather than passing them directly to **execute**:

```
cu.execute("INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (%s,%s,%s);", (a, b, c)) 
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i still get the same error but your answer gave me another idea so thank you!

Comment: @Shad, is that because **args** is in a list? Anyhow, glad it helps :) Happy new year by the way

Comment: @Shad, ah I see **args** will convert into 'a', 'b', 'c' as string... let me update my answer